# Getting my comments to appear within the assigned div container

Tags: css

This might be simple to do but for some reason I haven't been able to find any solution on the internet or even playing around with my code. I would like to have my message/comments to appear within the assigned div

```
SDSDSSDSDSSSDSDSDSSDSDSDS
DSSDSDSDSDSDSDSSSDSDSDSDSD
SSDSDSSDSDSSSDSDSDSSDSDSDS
DSSDSDSDSDSDSDSSSDSDSDSDSDS
```

for example instead of:

```
SDSDSSDSDSSSDSDSDSSDSDSDSDSSDSDSDSDSDSDSSSDSDSDSDSDSSDSDSSDSDSSSDSDSDSSDSDSDSDSSDSDSDSDSDSDSSSDSDSDSDSDS
```

Comment doesn't even do double lines for the long letter like shown above as well- simply that message will go on a single line across the entire site

**/comments/_comment**

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<% commentable.comments.reverse.each do |comment| %>
 <div class="well">
  <%= image_tag comment.user.avatar.url(:medium), class: 'comment_image' %>
  <div class="arrow_box">
   <ul class'messagebox'><%= comment.text %></ul>
   <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> <strong>ago</strong>
  </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

**CSS - comments.css**

```
.well {
  width: 400px;
}
.comment_container {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 150px;
  width: 400px;
}

.comment_next_to_picture {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 240px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.profile_comment_box {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.profile_comments_box {
  float: right;
}

.arrow_box {
  position: relative;
  background: #3e5361;
  border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
  border-color: rgba(62, 83, 97, 0);
  border-right-color: #3e5361;
  border-width: 30px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
  border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
  border-right-color: #c2e1f5;
  border-width: 36px;
  margin-top: -36px;
 }
```

For further question please ask. Thank you again for all advice and solution to this problem.

Comment: check   `.your-element{ word-wrap:break-work;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `white-space` AND `word-break` since there are **no spaces** in your string.

```css
.wrap {
  /*
  * To make this cross-browser compatible, you'll need to address each browser.
  * Hence, the multiple "white-space"
  */

  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;
  white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap;
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: normal;
}

/* This div is only for styling purposes */
div { width:100px; margin:10px; background:#ddd; }
```

```html
<div>LONGSTRINGWITHNOSPACESLONGSTRINGWITHNOSPACESLONGSTRINGWITHNOSPACESLONGSTRINGWITHNOSPACESLONGSTRINGWITHNOSPACESLONGSTRINGWITHNOSPACES</div>

<div class="wrap">LONGSTRINGWITHNOSPACESLONGSTRINGWITHNOSPACESLONGSTRINGWITHNOSPACESLONGSTRINGWITHNOSPACESLONGSTRINGWITHNOSPACESLONGSTRINGWITHNOSPACES</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! just learned something new :) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: `white-space` is not required considering the case of OP.

Comment: The OP's example string does not contain spaces

Comment: Exactly, so what will break the text is `word-wrap:break-word`, `white-space:pre-wrap` doesn't have an effect in the particular case. http://jsbin.com/ravalisaha/edit?html,css,output